# How to match string in switch

Tags: go

I'm converting a byte slice to a string and trying to catch this in a switch case. (Not sure how to catch byte slices, therefore conversion).

I can't figure out how to get my switch statement to work.

What am I missing?

```
package main

import "os/exec"

func main() {

    // Query existing layout
    cmd, _ := exec.Command("setxkbmap", "-query").Output()

    // Retrieve the language, cant figure out a better way
    lang   := string(cmd[len(cmd)-3:])

    // Switch to the other language
    var newLang string

   print(lang) // prints gb

    switch lang {
      case "se": newLang = "gb"
      case "gb": newLang = "se"
    }

    print(newLang) // prints nothing

    // set new layout
    exec.Command("setxkbmap", "-layout", newLang)
}
```

Comment: What exactly isn't working here?

Comment: Problems with newlines you do not see?

Comment: Added more info. @Volker care to expand? Thanks

Comment: https://play.golang.com/p/tTbCa5zhpqM works just fine. (Keep in mind that print is not println)

Comment: @mkopriva I think the problem is that when i do the string conversion from byte slice to string (lang := string...)

Comment: Then try `fmt.Printf("%q\n", lang)` to see the whole string surrounded by quotes, maybe you have spaces there which you won't see with `print`.

Comment: The byte conversion is definitely not the problem. It's something else. As volker & mkopriva have both suggested, check for whitespace or other non-visible characters in your byte slice. https://play.golang.com/p/B75u23PSGdA

Answer (score 1):

Given the output of `setxkbmap -query` can have multiple rows, and the value you are looking for (which I assume is `layout`) isn't necessarily always the last one printed, I suggest reading each line of the output, checking for the `layout:` field and then assigning the value.

For example:

```
out, err := exec.Command("setxkbmap", "-query").Output()
if err != nil {
    return err
}
var layout string
s := bufio.NewScanner(bytes.NewReader(out))
for s.Scan() {
    fields := strings.Fields(s.Text())
    if len(fields) != 2 {
        continue
    }
    if fields[0] == "layout:" {
        layout = fields[1]
        break
    }
}
switch layout {
case "gb":
    // handle gb layout
    fmt.Println("got gb layout")
    return nil
default:
    return fmt.Errorf("unexpected layout: %q", layout)
}
```